# Unsatisfied dependency

Tags: quarkus

I'm currently facing an issuer with a RestEasy filter. I try to implement a filter where I inject the `SecurityIdentity` like the following:

```java
@Provider
public class CustomFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{

    @Inject
    SecurityIdentity securityIdentity;
```

The fact is I have a compilation error:

```bash
[ERROR]         [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dep
endency for type io.quarkus.security.identity.SecurityIdentity and qualifiers [@Default]
[ERROR]         - java member: xx.xxx.xxx.xx.xx.CustomFilter #securityIdentity
[ERROR]         - declared on CLASS bean [types=[jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter, xx.xxx.xxx.xx.xx.CustomFilter, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], targ
et=xx.xxx.xxx.xx.xx.CustomFilter]
```

I tried to create a producer but the `SecurityIdentity` is an interface.

After reading many issues found on stackoverflow and try to debug if many hours, I need help.

The filter is located in a library and compiled well until I add the `@Inject SecurityIdentity`.

Thanks for your help,

SL

Comment: Which Quarkus extensions are you using?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

I'm just using resteasy-reactive

Answer (score 1):

Looks good. It appears that I need to add the `quarkus-oidc` extension.